# Android Audio Policy, defined devices and default routing

Tags: android, audio, android-ndk, android-audiomanager

I am currently facing an issue which Android Audio Policy using Android Nougat.
I have an Android device which has :

- An USB Handset connected
- An audio jack output
- Potentially a Bluetooth device

Those devices are declared using a specific audio_policy_configuration.xml as explained in Android documentation ( https://source.android.com/devices/audio/implement-policy )

2 apps are mainly running on the device :

- One is supposed to play only through the USB Handset
- The other is supposed to play only through the audio jack

If another app is added, it should also play only through the audio jack (default behavior of our device)

However the current behavior is that the USB is taking over all sounds if connected. I dig a bit around the C++ code of Android Audio Policy, but I am struggling to connect the dots.

I know Android is providing an API to force the audio output for an application but I would like to know if it is possible to modify the way Android handles its outputs directly, through the configuration. Ideally, still define all the different outputs, but only have the audio jack as the "default output".

In the older version of Android, it seems that this order was hard-coded :

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/322b4d2/services/audiopolicy/enginedefault/src/Engine.cpp

```
            // when not in a phone call, phone strategy should route STREAM_VOICE_CALL to A2DP
            if (!isInCall() &&
                    (mForceUse[AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_FOR_MEDIA] != AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_NO_BT_A2DP) &&
                    (outputs.getA2dpOutput() != 0)) {
                device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_BLUETOOTH_A2DP;
                if (device) break;
                device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_BLUETOOTH_A2DP_HEADPHONES;
                if (device) break;
            }
            device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADPHONE;
            if (device) break;
            device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADSET;
            if (device) break;
            device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_USB_DEVICE;
            if (device) break;
            if (!isInCall()) {
                device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_USB_ACCESSORY;
                if (device) break;
                device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_DGTL_DOCK_HEADSET;
                if (device) break;
                device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_AUX_DIGITAL;
                if (device) break;
                device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_ANLG_DOCK_HEADSET;
                if (device) break;
            }
            device = availableOutputDevicesType & AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_EARPIECE;
            if (device) break;
            device = mApmObserver->getDefaultOutputDevice()->type();
            if (device == AUDIO_DEVICE_NONE) {
                ALOGE("getDeviceForStrategy() no device found for STRATEGY_PHONE");
            }
            break;
```

When Nougat+ returns a list of devices:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/refs/heads/master/services/audiopolicy/enginedefault/src/Engine.cpp

```
            devices = availableOutputDevices.getDevicesFromType(AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_HEARING_AID);
            if (!devices.isEmpty()) break;
            // when not in a phone call, phone strategy should route STREAM_VOICE_CALL to A2DP
            if (!isInCall() &&
                    (getForceUse(AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_FOR_MEDIA) != AUDIO_POLICY_FORCE_NO_BT_A2DP) &&
                     outputs.isA2dpSupported()) {
                devices = availableOutputDevices.getFirstDevicesFromTypes({
                        AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_BLUETOOTH_A2DP,
                        AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_BLUETOOTH_A2DP_HEADPHONES});
                if (!devices.isEmpty()) break;
            }
            devices = availableOutputDevices.getFirstDevicesFromTypes({
                    AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADPHONE, AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_WIRED_HEADSET,
                    AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_LINE, AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_USB_HEADSET,
                    AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_USB_DEVICE});
            if (!devices.isEmpty()) break;
            if (!isInCall()) {
                devices = availableOutputDevices.getFirstDevicesFromTypes({
                        AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_USB_ACCESSORY, AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_DGTL_DOCK_HEADSET,
                        AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_AUX_DIGITAL, AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_ANLG_DOCK_HEADSET});
                if (!devices.isEmpty()) break;
            }
            devices = availableOutputDevices.getDevicesFromType(AUDIO_DEVICE_OUT_EARPIECE);
            break;
```

Thank you!